# Displaying a panel in another windows form on button click c#

Tags: c#, static, panel

I'm working on a c# program and I want a panel to appear on a form when a button is clicked in another. So when the add button is clicked on form2 the panel requesting the details for this to be possible will be displayed on form 1.

I currently have a static method set up in form1 which can be accessed from form2 - however due to `panel.Show()` being non static it won't allow me to use this in the function.

In Form1 I have:

```
public static void showPanel()
{
   panel.Show()
}
```

In my second form I have the following:

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   form1.showPanel();
   this.Hide();
}
```

I have tested with just having the static function show a message box which works. Is it possible to do it the way I want or do I need to take a few steps back and try a different technique?

Comment: Don't make the method static.

Comment: If the method isn't static it won't let me access it from my other form.

Comment: See mey two form project at following posting.  You need to use an instance of the form. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Raise an event in the 2nd form, one that the 1st one can easily subscribe.  Or pass a reference to your 1st form object through the form2 constructor.  Do favor an event.

Comment: @jdweng Using your post helped me get it working thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we talking about a new instance of the second form if so you can try to instantiate the new form using:

`Form newForm = new YourFormName(potential parameters);
newForm.showPanel();
newForm.Show();`

If you want to execute the form on an open form you can give the first form a reference(field with instance) of the second form. Or you can try using: `Application.OpenForms`. if you give it [1] it'll give you the second open form probably. You can also use `.OfType` to get the correct form in case your form order isn't always the same.

Comment: The panel I want to open is on form1, I want the static void to set this panel to be visible and I want to call it on a button click in form2

Comment: I'm not sure or you can use a static method in that context. if you want to influence an instance of an object I think you need to call a public non static method on this object. if you call Class.StaticMethod how would the code know that is has to influence this specific instance of that object?